# Can anyone post an example for event notification using docusign java-client sdk?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to implement event notification webhook method into my app. I am using docusign-java-client SDK for docusign, but I am unable to find any example using SDK. Can anyone provide some example to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to report that we (DocuSign) don't yet have a Java recipe for this. We do have a [Python example](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python). Java is on the list of things to do. Perhaps someone else can provide an example in the meantime.

Here is a general description:

First, set up your webhook subscription. You can have an envelope-specific webhook subscription by including the eventNotification fields in your envelope create request.

Or you can set up a more general subscription by using the "Connect" feature. You can setup Connect subscriptions either via the DocuSign web tool, or programmatically.

As part of the subscription you provide your url for the incoming XML notification messages.

To handle them, you write a small web app using whatever web app framework is easiest for you and your stack. Your web server will receive the incoming https calls from DocuSign.

You can see what the incoming XML messages look like by using the [beta Recipe Framework](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python). Run it on Heroku. Use the embedded signing recipe and click the button to see the Webhook / Connect messages. You can then see the sorts of messages that you will receive.

Your incoming message web server will simply parse the XML messages and then handle them accordingly.

Thanks for using the webhook system. Please ask more questions here if you have any issues.

Comment: what if I set eventNotification.setUseSoapInterface("false") in eventNotification, whould I get a json response in that case ?

Comment: No, sorry, not at this time. Currently all notifications are in XML format. JSON notifications are on the roadmap, but no date yet. To help raise the priority of the project, please ask your DocuSign technical or business representative to add your organization's name to the CONNECT-48 tracking issue. Thank you. @VijenderKumar